# how to use access token to call another post request?

Tags: node.js, access-token

I have this post request to get access token and its working fine but would like to know how can I use this access token to call another post request ? Or how do I use async or promises to use in this ?

Here is my code :

```
function getAccessToken() {
    const querystring = require('querystring');
    const https = require('https')
    const postData = querystring.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    });

 const options = {
   "hostname":'api.xxx.com',
   "method": "POST",
   "path" : "/token",
   "port" : 443,
   "encoding": "utf8",
   "followRedirect": true,
   "headers": {
     "Authorization": 'Basic ' + Buffer.from("client_id" + ':' + "client_secret").toString('base64'),
     "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(postData),
   },
   'muteHttpExceptions': true
 }
 const body = []
 const req = https.request(options, res => {
   console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
   res.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk))
   res.on('end', () => {
     const access_token = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
     console.log(access_token)
   })

 })
 req.on('error', error => {
   console.error(error)
 })
 req.write(postData);
 req.end()
}

getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save token in database,file or other memory database and use it in all requests in the Authorization header but depends on type of token,for example for set JWT token:

```
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken)
```

OR in option object:

```
options = {
  host: '<URL>',
  path: '<path of endpoint>',
  port: '<portNumber>',
  headers: {'Authorization', 'Bearer '+accessToken}
  };
```

also for the async request to another endpoint, you can use Axios [axios example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios):

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

const sendGetRequest = async () => {
   try {
      const resp = await 
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
         headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_JWT_TOKEN_HERE'
          }
      });

       console.log(resp.data);
      } catch (err) {
      // Handle Error Here
       console.error(err);
      }
 };

 sendGetRequest();
```